# Handling Events in GUI C# application

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

Why overriding the onclick method for example in a form (just overriding not calling) that will handle the event 
like in the picture :
[showing the onClick method would change the color but never been called only overrided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2HHv.png)

why this is happening why not using instead of publishing and registering the event

Comment: There is no reason why this is happening, unless you have an event attached somewhere, or alternatively you clicked somewhere in the form

Comment: Good class design demands that a class should never have to listen to its own events.  They are interesting to *other* classes, ones you don't know about and can't guess up front that they might be interested.  Not calling base.OnClick() is a bug, it prevents the Click event from getting raised.  Not listening to your own events is otherwise a rule that gets violated pretty frequently in Winforms, events are quite convenient in the designer.  Writing good Winforms code requires a keyboard, not a mouse :)

Comment: i mean i just override the method and this only raised the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you can access the object as a member from any part of your class and register to its event.
WinForms auto generates code which does the event firing and registration for you.

Comment: yes i see but why this is happening i just override the method i didn't register it to any event but once i override it handled the event as it told to be.